# Can Google URL Shortener's API provide many Short URLS for one Long URL?

Tags: api, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

Can Google URL Shortener's API provide many Short URLS for one Long URL?

I found if I do:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com"}'
```

it always outputs the same short url:

```
{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "http://goo.gl/fbsS",
 "longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are signed in to goo.gl using a Google Account, a unique
   short URL is generated each time a long URL is shortened.
2. If you are not signed in to goo.gl, the same short URL is reused
   each time a long URL is shortened, across multiple users.

http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=190768

Comment: I meant in reference of the Google API